# How to create a Toggle on/Off Function on a keypress in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, toggle, userscripts

I have a test script for part of my overall goal, but i need to create some sort of toggle on and off function. My code so far is:

```
tgl = "on"

function ToggleON() {
    console.log("on");
    tgl = "off"
}

function ToggleOFF() {
    console.log("off");
    tgl = "on"
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key == 81){
        if (tgl == "on") {
            ToggleON();
        }

        if (tgl == "off") {
            ToggleOFF();
        } 
    }
});
```

Any help is appriciated

Comment: Instead of `if (tgl=='off')` use `else`.

Comment: Just use an if/else statement inside of a `toggle` function to check if `tgl` is `on` or `off` and act accordingly. Then you'll have one `toggle` function instead of `toggleOn` and `toggleOff`.

Answer (score 0):

Closure could do the trick.

```
var toggle = function() {
    var on = false;
    return function() {
    if(!on) {
        on = true;
        //Do stuff if ON
        return;
    }
    //Do stuff if OFF
    on = false;
}
}();

toggle(); //Set OFF as default    

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {
   var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if(key === 81) {
      toggle();
   }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work. I would use boolean instead of strings 'on/off', shorter, simpler, clearer.

```
var tgl=true;

function toggle() {
    tgl?console.log('on'):console.log('off')
    tgl=!tgl;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key == 81)
        toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think taking the item being toggled in as an argument is the best way to go about doing this. This makes the `toggle` function useful to other areas in your code where you might need a `toggle` function.

```
var tgl = false;

function toggle(item) {
  item === true ? item = false : item = true;
  return item;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(key == 81)
    tgl = toggle(tgl);
}
```

If you'd rather it be on/off strings.

```
var tgl = "off";

function toggle(item) {
  item === "on" ? item = "off" : item = "on";
  return item;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(key == 81)
    tgl = toggle(tgl);
}
```

Comment: Did this solve your issue? Since you didnt upvote or accept a answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main {
    constructor() {
        this.state = 0;
        this.onLoad();
    }
    onLoad() {
        addEventListener('keydown', event => {
            if (event.key == 'q') {
                this.state ^= 1;
                this.result();
            }
        });
    }
    result() {
        console.log(this.state);
    }
}
const main = new Main();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).